# How to convert a time string to number of seconds in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time

I've got the following time string that I need to convert to a number of seconds since midnight (start of day).  I've been looking in the Ruby Api but haven't been able to come up with a solution.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
time_string = '4:12:38 PM ET'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert your string to a time use

```
new_time = Time.parse(time_string)
```

This will return a Time object. Then you can just subtract the time at midnight from your given time like so:

```
midnight = Time.local(2010,2,13,0,0,0)
seconds = (new_time - midnight).to_i # Number of seconds as an integer, .to_f works too
```

Of course, for Time.local, you should use today's date, not the hardcoded values as above.

Comment: That did the trick.  I was not using local in my earlier efforts.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the active_support installed you can also do this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'time'
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/calculations'

puts Time.parse('4:12:38 PM ET').seconds_since_midnight.to_i
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using. the require 'active_support..." line is returning a no such file error for me.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.7 but active_support is a external gem you must first install it: (sudo) gem install activesupport

Comment: You must install the active_support gem; it is not built into Ruby's standard library.

Comment: ActiveSupport is built into Rails, which is where a lot of people inherit it from, but, as the previous commenters said, you can install it separately.